# Anyway to limit IP Access for Certain Users?

Tags: windows, active-directory, user-management, ips

I am currently tasked with allowing Vendors onto our process network. The issue is I need to make it so each vendor is only able to connect to PLCs on their own machines "each PLC has its own IP". Is there a way to limit what IP addresses a windows user can connect to per user?

This is a windows environment running Rockwell Software "Allen Bradley PLCs"

Example:

User1@local.com can connect to PLCs on 172.20.10.10, 172.20.10.23, 172.20.40.28

User2@local.com can connect to PLCs on 172.20.10.90, 172.20.10.70, 172.20.40.20

User3@local.com can connect to PLCs on 172.20.10.99, 172.20.10.170, 172.20.40.92

Comment: Have the users connect through a VPN of some sort and then configure their VPN accounts with the desired network ACLs.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can set up IPsec policies based on computer group membership or IPs.  Depending on your AD version and clients, you could also use authentication silos.

Comment: Do you have any good examples of multiple IPSec policies that would accomplish this?